# Valor de un array undefined con for, forEach y otros

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

antes que nada busque varias preguntas relacionadas pero no me estarian ayudando con exactitud. Si llegase a ser el caso de ser repetida, no es mi intención.

Tengo un problema con varias llamadas $.getJSON que hacen .push a un array para luego sumar esos resultados.

Es decir:

```
   var f0 = "URL";
   var f1 = "URL1";
   var n0 = 0;
   var n1 = 0;

  let totalN = new Array();

  $.getJSON(f0)
   .then(function(data) {
    n0 = data.total;
    totalN.push(n0);
  })
   .fail(function() {
    n0 = 0;
  });
    $.getJSON(f1)
   .then(function(data) {
    n1 = data.total;
    totalN.push(n1);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    n1 = 0;
  });
```

Al hacer un `console.log(totalN)` me imprime lo siguiente:

[image: console.log de totalN]

Luego de esto trate de hacer la suma total de todos utilizando `for` y tambien intente con `forEach`.

Pero luego note que al hacer un array en limpio, en console log figura `array(11)` por ejemplo, siendo 11 el total de `length`. Pero en mi caso, no figura. Entonces deduje, que ese era un motivo por el cual el `for` o `forEach` no procesaba los valores.

¿Que esta mal?

Ya que tengo entendido, .push es utilizado para insertar valores dentro de un array existente. Y data.total (en cada getJSON) trae un valor equivalente a "12345". Tengo entendido, que fuese numero o string, lo inserta igualmente.

Este seria un archivo .json (procesado en Firefox), indicando que tomo el valor `.total` unicamente.

[image: Archivo JSON]

Comment: Podrías hacer un `console.log` de `n0` y `n1`

Comment: Hola, Gracias Cesar... Lo hice y , imprimen:  `0` los dos, pero es raro ya que al hacer console.log(totalN) (del array) los valores son los tomados del `JSON` .

Comment: Cuando realizas la petición $.getJSON en el .then(data =>{ data.total}), acá capturás el valor y luego hacer el push al array, entiendo, y entiendo que en algún momento cuando haces console.log(totalN) en efecto te muestra la información?

Probá realizar esto declara una variable x = null y en el .then realizas x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), posteriormente n0 = x.total y realizar el push.

También verifica que tu totalN se esté inicializando, realizá un console.log(totalN) al inicio para verificar que si esté vacío.

Comment: Hola, probe y me di cuenta que dentro de cada $.getJSON el console.log de totalN da correctamente un array(11), pero fuera sige dando el array() sin indice. Y luego, el console log de totalN (removiendo los $.getJSON) figuran correctos, vacios. Pero poniendo los $.getJSON con los push, ya figuran con la data insertada como en la imagen.

Comment: Luego fuera de los $.getJSON los n0,n1 dan = 0, pero dentro dan = a x.total :/ Habria que hacerlo de otra forma?